# Error when using SciTE

Tags: errors, context, editors

I get the following error when trying to compile a file using SciTE for ConTeXt:

```
mtxrun          | kpse fallback with progname 'context' initialized in 0.381 seconds>Exit code: 1
```

I followed all of the instructions given [here](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Windows_Installation%3a_ConTeXt_Suite_with_SciTe), but nothing promising so far. Has anyone else experienced this error?

Comment: Can you compile a file using command line? I don't use SciTE and it is hard to debug using truncated error messages from the editors.

Comment: @Aditya I do not compile from the command line. This is my first attempt at compiling using ConTeXt.

Comment: remove all data and copy again from `texmf-dist/context/data/scite/*` remember to change the size of the font in `scite-context.properties`. Or the other option would be to to add `file.patterns.context=*.tex;*.tui;*.tuo;*.sty;
filter.context=ConTeXt|$(file.patterns.context)|lexer.$(file.patterns.context)=tex
command.compile.$(file.patterns.context)=
command.build.$(file.patterns.context)=texexec --pdf $(FileNameExt)
command.go.$(file.patterns.context)=acroread $(FileName).pdf` in `SciTEUser.properties` too. I don't use scite. Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

I solved the issue by installing SciTE from the original website ([link](http://www.scintilla.org/SciTEDownload.html)). I copied the lexer add-in and the settings instructed, but I also had to create a batch file with the following instructions:

```
rem Use to start SciTE for ConTeXt
@echo off
c:
cd C:\context\tex
call setuptex
cd C:\wscite
start scite.exe %1%
```

Note that you can change the path for context and SciTE. Remember to put context into the environment variable path under advanced system properties.